# Is $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ self-opposite?

Tags: linear-algebra, ring-theory

Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $K$.

Is $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ a self-opposite $K$-algebra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If "self opposite" means "isomorphic to its opposite ring," then **no.**

If you take an infinite dimensional $V$, then it is known that the ring of linear transformations written on the left is right self-injective but not left self-injective. So it cannot be isomorphic to its opposite ring.

In the finite dimensional case, the answer is **yes**, of course, by using the transposition map.

Comment: Dear rschwieb: Thank you very much for your prompt answer! Would you have a reference for the facts you invoke? (I mean, the facts you invoke in the infinite dimensional case.)

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard I'm pretty sure it's in Lam's *Lectures on modules and rings*, which I don't have in front of me at the moment. From googlebooks, I think the reference on page 263 *readers with a good memory will recall there exist von Neumann regular rings which are left self-injective but not right self injective (See 3.74B)* is to page 63, which I can't see in googlebooks. I think that's where it is.

Comment: Dear : You're right! In the edition I have in front of me, the statements are contained in Sections (3.74A) p. 97 and (3.74B) p. 98. Thank you very much again!